# Azure Blob Storage for C# List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, database, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently developing my first small App with Xamarin.Forms and Azure for the database backend.
My users would be able to write comments on some topic.

Currently I'm using Azure (Block) Blob Storage with one blob for each topic.
A C# List object containing all comments is serialized to JSON and then stored in this blob. To post something new I download the whole thing, deserialize it, add the new entry, then serialize and upload it again.

I'm guessing there are more elgant ways to do this... It would be great if I could add new comments separately and only download what I really need.

Thanks a lot

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using [azure table storage.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables)

Azure Table storage is a service that stores structured NoSQL data in the cloud, providing a key/attribute store with a schemaless design.

You could design your table as below:

Partitionkey: topic id or name

Rowkey: comments-date or user-id

Property: Content, or something else

Then if you want to search the topic's content, you could directly search the table according to partition-key. It will just return the right topic data.

If you want to insert new value, you could directly insert the value to that partition.